# Condition for vector to be in a plane

Tags: vectors, cross-product

Suppose $\ell$ and $m$ are non-parallel lines with direction vectors $v$ and $w$, respectively. Let $u$ be a vector of the line $\ell$. Then a vector $x$ is on the plane $V$ spanned by $ℓ$ and $m$ if and only if:

- a) $x \bullet(v \times w) = u \bullet (v \times w) $
- b) $x \bullet(v \times w) = u $
- c) $v \bullet(x \times w) = u \bullet (v \times w) $
- d) $x \bullet(v \times w) = 0 $

Are there multiple correct choices? I believe a) and d) are the same, since $u$ should be perpendicular to the normal vector of the plane. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: The question seems to assume that lines $l$ and $m$ intersect, so that they define a plane. Note that the lines and this plane $V$ do not need to go through the origin. The vector $u$ points to any point on line $l$, so this vector is not necessarily parallel to the plane $V$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the geometric interpretation of [triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product) the two volumes

- $V_1=x \bullet(v \times w)$
- $V_2=u \bullet (v \times w)$

are the same since the components of $x$ and $u$ onto $v \times w$ are the same therefore the correct statement is "a)".

As noticed by [Jaap Scherphuis](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/362967/jaap-scherphuis) in the comments, another way to see that if $u$ and $x$ both (when placed at the origin) point to points within the plane, it means $u−x$ is parallel to the plane. From this we can deduce that "a)" is the only correct anwer. Moreover, if the plane happens to go through the origin then (c) and (d) hold as well, but not in general.

Comment: The plane $V$ does not necessarily go through the origin. I believe that by "a vector of the line $l$" they mean a vector that points from the origin to any point on $l$, which is not necessarily parallel to $l$.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Yes indeed I was assuming that! I fix accordingly, Thanks

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Opsssss...thanks! I'll look it again.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Last trial! :)

Comment: If $u$ and $x$ both (when placed at the origin) point to points within the plane, it means $u-x$ is parallel to the plane. From this you can deduce that (a) is the only correct anwer. If the plane happens to go through the origin then (c) and (d) hold as well, but not in general.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Opsss yes of course, geometrically the volume of the parallelepiped is the same. I had that in mind but I get confused!

Comment: @JaapScherphuis If you don't mind I've inserted your contribution into the answer in order to preserve that. Otherwise you could add your own answer.